# Rails: accepts_nested_attributes_for explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I'm using `Mongoid` and `rails_admin` gem for my rails application. Here is my two model files:

Model `Category`

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :tags
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags  # this line will be added later
end
```

Model `Tag`

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  embedded_in :category
end
```

When I run admin page (generated by `rails_admin`), I meet exception. In this exception, there is a message tell me that I should put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag` in `Category` model. After I put that line, no error appears.

So, my question is: Please explain for me purpose of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I see many tutorials, often those two lines use together:

```
   embeds_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
```

So why ? Why not only one line ?

@Edit: I also read this link. But I still not understand so much. [explanation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

*Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off and you can enable it using the #accepts_nested_attributes_for class method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model.*

In other words accepts nested attributes allows you to save the tags directly from the category model ( that's rails)

The embeds_many on the other hand is to add the relation between the category and tag (that's mongoid). it would still be valid without #accepts_nested_attributes but won't allow you to save both in one step from the parent.

A good example to this:

Enabling nested attributes on a one-to-one association allows you to create the member and avatar in one go:

```
params = { member: { name: 'Jack', avatar_attributes: { icon: 'smiling' } } } 
# both member and avatar passed in one hash
member = Member.create(params[:member])
member.avatar.id # => 2
member.avatar.icon # => 'smiling'
```

A very nice video to further explain the concept can be found [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: can you explain for me about `won't allow you to save both in one step from the parent` please. Maybe the word "one step" make me feel confuse. Because I can save tag inside category successfully (using mongoid). Thanks :)

Comment: i think a good example is the one-to-one example in the docs i will add it to the answer

Comment: if you can see my comment in the example both member and avatar params passed to the create function of member in one hash and is accepted by member to create the nested resource

Comment: If you don't have accepts_nested_attribute on only the member will be created the avatar data will be rejected.

Comment: also a very good resource to check this is this [cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)